# A question about the ring of continuous functions on $[0,1]$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am reading Andreas Gathmann's Commutative Algebra notes. I am reading Chapter 2, and I am struggling with Exercise 2.11.

"Let $R$ be the ring of all continuous real-valued functions on the unit interval $[0,1]$.
Similarly to Definition 0.3 (c), for any subset $S$ of $R$ we denote by
$$V(S) := \{a \in [0,1] : f(a) = 0 \text{ for all } f \in S\} \subset [0,1]$$
the zero locus of S. Prove:

(a) For all $a \in [0,1]$ the ideal $I_a := \{f \in R : f(a) = 0\}$ is maximal.

(b) If $f_1,...,f_n \in R$ with $V(f_1,...,f_n)=\varnothing$, then $f_1^2+···+f_n^2$ is invertible in $R$.

(c) For any ideal $I \trianglelefteq R$ with $I \neq R$ we have $V(I) \neq \varnothing$."

(This exercise has part (d), but I will not write it here because I haven't done it yet)

I solved successfully part (a) and (b), however I am stuck  at part (c). At first, I think of proving the equivalent statement of part (c), which is "If $V(I)=\varnothing$ then $I=R$". And I actually proved for a specific form of the ideal $I$, that is $I=(f_1,\dots,f_n)$ where the functions $f_k$ have no roots over $[0,1]$. However, since $C[0,1]$ is not a PID, or even not all of its ideals are finitely generated, I have no idea what to do to generalize my proof or to prove in some other ways.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall part (b): If $f_1,...,f_n \in R$ satisfy $V(f_1,...,f_n)=\emptyset$, then $g=f_1^2+···+f_n^2$ is invertible in $R$, so every $h \in R$ can be written as $g \cdot (h/g)$, whence the ideal generated by $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ is  $R$.
Thus for every finite subset $F=\{f_1,\ldots,f_n\}$ of the ideal $I \ne R$, we must have $V(F) \ne \emptyset$. Therefore, the collection
$$\{V(F): F \;\; \text{a finite subset of} \;\; I\}$$
is a collection of closed subsets of $[0,1]$ with the finite intersection property:
If $F_1,\ldots,F_k \subset I$ are finite, then
$$\cap_{j=1}^k V(F_j)=V(\cup_{j=1}^k F_j) \ne \emptyset \,.$$
By one of the equivalent definition of compactness (number 5 in [1])
$$V(I)=\bigcap\{V(F): F \;\; \text{a finite subset of} \;\; I\} \ne \emptyset \,.$$

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space#Equivalent_definitions

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But I still have one more question about your solution. Could you explain clearer why $V(\{f_1,...,f_n\}) \neq \varnothing$?

Comment: I will add an explanation to my answer.